# getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'queryService' of undefined

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

I'm trying to add an Excel export button to a Kendo UI grid. When the button is clicked I keep getting the following error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'queryService' of undefined'. I'm using Angular 8.2 with AOT and lazy route loading.

Here is my component's html:

```
<kendo-grid [data]="ProcessedMessageQueueGridData | async" [selectable]="true" [height]="gridHeight"
      (sortChange)="sortChange($event)"
      (selectionChange)="selected($event)" (dataStateChange)="onStateChange($event)"
      (detailExpand)="onDetailExpand($event)" id="ProcessedMessageQueueGrid">
      <ng-template kendoGridToolbarTemplate>
        <button tooltip="Export PDF" kendoGridPDFCommand>
          <fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'file-pdf']"></fa-icon>
        </button>
        <button tooltip="Export to Excel" kendoGridExcelCommand>
          <fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'file-excel']"></fa-icon>
        </button>
      </ng-template>
      <kendo-grid-column *ngFor="let column of columns" field="{{column.field}}" title="{{column.title}}"
        sortable="true" filterable="{{column.filterable}}" filter="{{column.filter}}" format="{{column.format}}"
        [hidden]="hiddenColumns.indexOf(column.field) > -1">
      </kendo-grid-column>
      <div *kendoGridDetailTemplate="let dataItem">
        <app-ccmis-history [rampid]="dataItem.rampID"></app-ccmis-history>
      </div>
      <kendo-grid-pdf fileName="ProcessedMessageQueue.pdf" [allPages]="true">
        <kendo-grid-pdf-margin top="1cm" left="1cm" right="1cm" bottom="1cm"></kendo-grid-pdf-margin>
      </kendo-grid-pdf>
      <kendo-grid-excel fileName="ProcessedMessageQueue.xlsx" [fetchData]="allData"></kendo-grid-excel>
    </kendo-grid>
```

Here is my component.ts file:

```
constructor(public queryService: ProcessedMessageQueueQueryService) {}

public allData(st?: any): Observable<any> {
        const state = Object.assign({}, st);
        delete state.skip;
        delete state.take;
        return this.queryService.fetch(state).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$));
    }
```

I tried using some of the example code from the Kendo UI Grid documentation but still got the same error. I also tried turning off AOT with no success. I can figure out why I'm getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<kendo-grid-excel fileName="ProcessedMessageQueue.xlsx" [fetchData]="allData"></kendo-grid-excel>
```

The error occurs because the function `allData` is being passed to the kendo grid excel component. `allData` is executed within the kendo component and in that context, `this` no longer references the component it is intended to. `this` instead references the kendo component where `queryService` is undefined.

In `component.ts` try this I believe it will work:

```
public allDataProperlyBound: any = this.allData.bind(this);
```

Then update kendo grid excel

```
<kendo-grid-excel fileName="ProcessedMessageQueue.xlsx" [fetchData]="allDataProperlyBound">
```

Check out the docs on [.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) for more info.